# Autodetect Raspberry-Pi Camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a question, is there a way to detect the Raspi Camera **HW** Module? I'm coding a project in Python and I need to verify if the Camera hardware module is attached to the RPi or not since I need to replicate the same Python project to several RPis but some of them won't have the camera connected. I'm using the Picamera SW module, but I was thinking something like importing such module if the camera existist somewhere in the **/dev** tree, does anybody now if this is possible or a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it raise an error when you initialize the picamera class if the camera is not connected? or does it do nothing ... what if you try to capture an image with no camera attached ... is the image size 0 or somehting?

Comment: Hi Joran, actually my initial idea was as you're describing, using the O.S. command: "raspistill" for taking the snapshot before runing the python project at boot. One thing for sure is the .jpeg won't be there, forget about the size, the problem was that whem trying to use Python, it rises an exception when trying to take a snapshot and I really needed only is to detect the condition when it is there or not, now I've implemented a solution that worked, I'll post it in the main Thread, many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this the solution I've found after googling some is the command **vcgencmd**, which serves for detecting if the camera is connected or not, so by issuing Python to execute a subprocess I've managed to get the desired results

The O.S. command "vcgencmd get_camera" gives the outout:

```
supported=0 detected=0
```

So by using a subprocess python call:

```
import subprocess
c = subprocess.check_output(["vcgencmd","get_camera"])
int(camdet.strip()[-1]) #-- Removes the final CR character and gets only the "0" or "1" from detected status

if (c):
    print "Camera detected"
else:
    print "not detected"
```

Hope this is useful for somebody else, any simpler sugested solutions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I use this to check if picamera is available, based in last post.
if you get supported and detected with value 1 you have available picamera

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
#--next line returns something like supported=1 detected=1
#--if get supported and deteted valued at 1 you have a picamera available    
commandResult = subprocess.check_output("vcgencmd get_camera", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

first line will give output of the command which is:
supported=1 detected=1
after that we use Python RegEx (Regular Expression) which can be imported by: **import re**
it will find all digits values in strings and return them. we convert them to int to be sure it is either 0 or 1.
and on third line unpack the list to get two values separately.

Now you can use these values in your python script to check the camera status in Raspberry.

```
import re
import subprocess

commandResult = subprocess.getoutput("vcgencmd get_camera")
commandResult = [int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', commandResult)]
camera_Supported , camera_Detected = commandResult
print ("commandResult is: ", commandResult)
print ("camera_Supported is: ", camera_Supported)
print ("camera_Detected is: ", camera_Detected)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?